# Grails create custom script that call grails commands

Tags: grails

I'm tring to create a grails scritp ('grails create-script foo') that should receive two arguments.
In it's implematition, it should  call some command lines like: generate-views and generate-controllers and others commands, passing one of the parameters received.

So far I've got this:
    includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

```
target(foo: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    def arguments= args
    //grails create-controller arguments
}

setDefaultTarget(foo)
```

Anyone knows how to do this? Call a grails command inside a custom script?

Obs: I'm using grails 2.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as easy as including the scripts you want to use in yours via `includeTargets << grailsScript()`.

The available scripts are located in your Grails install directory under `scripts`.

In your case you might want to look at the contents of `_GrailsCreateArtifacts.groovy`.

Once you've included the correct script(s), all you need to do is call the corresponding closure.

**Update**
The Generate-XXX scripts are provided by the scaffolding plugin. This plugin (in zip form) is located under the `plugins` directory of your Grails install. In the zip file you will find a `scripts` directory which has all the scripts for the plugin. Including the `GenerateViews.groovy`.